# Bots added to server are getting autobalanced

Tags: team-fortress-2

I am trying to make bots fight each other on my private TF2 server, but when I add a bot, the game adds other bots to balance out the teams.  How can I stop it from doing that?

Comment: Check your [bot quota server variables](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Bots) and some of the [team balance variables](http://forums.srcds.com/viewtopic/5567).

Comment: Why would that be a problem, if you want them to fight each other? If you want one team of bots and another of players, it's probably gonna remove a bot on a team if a player joins that team.

Comment: Are you trying to make players fight bots, or have bots fight bots?